# Unable to login to local Grafana installed with helm on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana, grafana-loki

I cannot login to Grafana via http://localhost:3000 on Windows after installing loki via helm on a K8S cluster hosted on GCP. I am following the official documentation here: https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/microservices-helm/
Once I login to my K8S cluster on GCP, I install loki+grafana via:

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace=monitoring promtail grafana/promtail --set "loki.serviceName=loki"
helm upgrade --install loki --namespace=monitoring grafana/loki-distributed
helm install --namespace=monitoring loki-grafana grafana/grafana
```

But when I arrive to this command to return the admin password to login, the full command returns seemingly the entire json response:

```
kubectl get secret --namespace monitoring loki-grafana -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode ; echo
```

but if I only do

```
kubectl get secret --namespace monitoring loki-grafana -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}"
```

> UFlPV1dDUkw3NkVxdlFNTU84UXpPMHVkbW9PeXNrTUY5Z3lFeXR....
> Then to expose the port:

```
kubectl port-forward service/loki-grafana 3000:80 -n monitoring
```

Then access the GUI via local web-browser at http:localhost:3000.
I get denied with user="admin", password="UFlPV1dDUkw3NkVxdlFNTU84UXpPMHVkbW9PeXNrTUY5Z3lFeXR...."

I am not sure how to debug this process. I installed base64 via chocolatey in the admin powershell via: `choco install base64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you should base64 decode the password before entering it into the UI. If that doesn‘t help you could restart the grafsna pod.

Comment: Ah I did not realize I had to decode the return, I thought it came decoded already. https://www.base64decode.org/ Did the trick! Thank you for pointing that out to me.